# Can I do strict socket bind for a client ip address at server side?

Tags: sockets, bind

I need to accept only connections from particular client ip address at server side. Should not use acl. With help of socket strict bind at server side can i do?

Example:

client ip address: 1.1.1.1
server ip address: 1.1.1.2

At server side:
1. Open a socket
2. Bind socket with 1.1.1.1(client ip address) with port no.

Will i be allow to do the second step at server side? Any special options are there to do?

Please let me know.

Thanks,
Boobesh

Comment: Why? For what purpose? aside from the fact that it's impossible, it also doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can only bind the server port to an ip address to specify the interface to use.

For example your server has two network interfaces, one connected to the internet and one to a configuration network. The webserver should maybe only listen on the internet interface and a management tool only listen on the configuration network.

For your purpose you can accept the connection, compare the ip address and if it is not in the list of allowed clients close the connection immediately (or after sending an error message).

The other solution would be to use a firewall that is configured to allow only connections from the specified clients to the server port.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the friend above, u can only manage the ip and port in you server, but not client. u should compare the coming socket with the one u store in your server.